# How to get data from remote server to Android and put in array?

Tags: php, android

I have been looking for a way to do this. I searched a lot but I have not find any topic match my needs. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AJAX request to retrieve data from the server, make sure that in the allowed hosts file in your app you ensure the app can access your server.